# Angular 2 - Run services within classes

Tags: angular, service

I'm new to Angular 2. I'm working on an e-commerce site and I have designed some basic classes for users, items, bids, etc... My User class has many parameters, some of them are:

```
export class User {
    id:             number;
    name:           string;
    email:          string;
    ...
    notifications:  Notification[];
}
```

The Notification class, has only two parameters as follows:

```
export class Notification {
    notification:       string;
    read:               boolean;
}
```

I have one service for users and one for notifications.

The situation is this: when an user read a notification, I have to make a request to the server to change the value of the 'read flag' of the notification in my database. To do this, in my component, I can do:

```
this.notificationService.changeToRead(user.notifications[x]).subscribe(...);
```

In the previous line I imagine that notificationService is an instance of NotificationService which has a method called changeToRead(notification: Notification) which executes the request.

My problem with this is that it's seems to procedural, and I want a more object oriented solution like:

```
user.notifications[x].changeToRead();
```

To do this, I must have the method changeToRead() in the class Notification, but it's seems that I can't inject a service into a class... But even if I could, I don't want as much instances of services as notifications I have...

I'm not sure if I'm clear because of my poor english, but I need to find a solution to make my request more object oriented like...

Any ideas?

Comment: any reason for using this `class`. It muse be decorated with a `@Component`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider building your Angular application using the current Angular patterns and not bring in OOP patterns that are not of common use in Angular.

With that said, I was able to "inject" a service into my class using something like this:

In the class:

```
    constructor(private productService: ProductService) {

     }
```

In the component code that uses the class:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let product = new IProduct(this.productService);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, I have tried "injecting" a service as you say, but I seems not to "clean".

What do you mean when you say "current Angular patterns"? Is the correct way of programming in Angular injecting the service in the component and using it in a procedural way? I mean, I was searching the way of using OOP because I thought it is cleanest, but if not, I'll do as ever...

Comment: Yes, it is the "correct" way of programming in Angular to inject services into a component. Not sure how that is "procedural". The service is just a singleton object and you call methods on it using OOP techniques.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Well, I will continue as ever so! Thank you so much @DeborahK